# > library("factoextra") Error in library("factoextra") : there is no package called ‘factoextra’

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

I've been trying to install the package factoextra to do pca plots.
However, when I try to install the packages it says it is already installed and it asks me to restart the r session.

Then when I'm trying to load the library it says

```
> library("factoextra")
Error in library("factoextra") : there is no package called ‘factoextra’
```

What did i do wrong?
I'm using R  >3.5 in windows.

Comment: I solved it by doing this if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/factoextra")

Comment: btw if you are using R version 3.5, you really should upgrade ... v3.5 is nearly 5 years old.